# What is the best way to store Users list for a Authorize attribute in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to specify authorize attibute with list of users.

This works:

`[Authorize(Users ="g@gmail.com, m@gmail.com")]`

But I want to store list of users in one place

I've tried to store them in appSettings:

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key= "admins" value="g@gmail.com, m@gmail.com" />
    </appSettings>
```

And then make a custom attribute:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            public MyAuthorizeAttribute()
            {
                this.Users = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["admins"];
            }
        }
```

And use it before controller:

```
[MyAuthorize]
```

But for some reasons that doesn't work.

If you have any idea on how to realise my purpose or fix my code, please, write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally have 2 ways of dealing with this.

For you it looks like I would stick with AD groups.

So have a file like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Models
{

    public static class AccessLevelRoles
    {
        public const string Admin = "DOMAIN\\MYGROUP";
    }
}
```

Then you can protect your actions/controllers by using.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = AccessLevelRoles.Admin)]
```

That's probably the easiest way and what you are looking for.